# How to Sync Main Net together with Test3 Net

Tags: synchronization, testnet

After I install the bitcoin core, it just sync the main net.

Is there a way that I can also sync the test3 net for testing/developing purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start another instance of Bitcoin Core with the `-testnet` option to run it in testnet mode.